# Mobile responsive table with HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a table that has 2 header columns and 4 columns of links. Example code below.

```css
table{
    border: 1px solid black;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:100%
}


th, td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

td {
  width:25%;
}
```

```html
 
<table class="fixed-width">
   <tr>
      <th colspan=2>header 1</th>
      <th colspan=2>header 234567895678657</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>data asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</td>
      <td>data 2</td>
      <td>link 3</td>
      <td>link 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>data asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</td>
      <td>data 2</td>
      <td>link 3</td>
      <td>link 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>data asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</td>
      <td>data 2</td>
      <td>link 3</td>
      <td>link 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>data asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</td>
      <td>data 2</td>
      <td>link 3</td>
      <td>link 4</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pse6thr8/21/

I would like the table to look something like this when a mobile accesses it.
[New Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLpLm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 different approaches to do that...

1. Using **Bootstrap columns** or
2. Collapse to **Tabs or accordion on smaller view**

First check how bootstrap columns will work,

first of all, add Bootstrap.min.css file to your  like this,

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

[Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pse6thr8/22/)

**and then your HTML will be like this,**

```
<div class="col-sm-6">

<table class="fixed-width">
   <tr>
      <th colspan=2>header 1</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>data asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</td>
      <td>data 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>data asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</td>
      <td>data 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>data asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</td>
      <td>data 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>data asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</td>
      <td>data 2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-6">

<table class="fixed-width">
   <tr>
      <th colspan=2>header 234567895678657</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>link 3</td>
      <td>link 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>link 3</td>
      <td>link 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>link 3</td>
      <td>link 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>link 3</td>
      <td>link 4</td>
   </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

and add this css as,

```
.col-sm-6{
  padding:0px
}
```

2. Collapse to **Tabs or accordion on smaller view**

[Check this codepen by csstricks](http://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/PNpMaj)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I only have 1 concern, is it possible for whatever reason that the bootstrap.css would be unavailable?

Comment: For this example I have added it from CDN, what you can do that, download that file from here getbootstrap.com so, there will be no problem because it will be hosted by you

Comment: Thankyou so much. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the media query also please try this

```
@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    /*
        Styles for display width 
        between 769 and 979 pixels
    */
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    /*
        Styles for display width 
        equal to 768 pixels and thinner
    */
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    /*
        Styles for display width 
        equal to 1200 pixels and wider
    */
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example? This is part of a sharepoint page, so it may or may not be compatible. The rest of the page i'm developing on is mobile responsive, I just need this table to behave the same.

Comment: Bootstrap does not make what he wants. Bootstrap just make table horizontaly scrollable. What he wants, you cant achieve with table tags. He have to change it to divs or more tables with media queries.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML table rows cannot separate from each other like the way you need them to. 
First of all you need to separate your left and right table. So that when you write the correct css, the one on the right would go down below of the first table.

After separating them, write width specific css for the device.

Like this;

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

td {
  width: 25%;
}
@media (max-width:500px){
  table{width:100%}
}
```

```html
<table class="fixed-width" style="border-right:none;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">header 1</th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</td>
      <td>data 2</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</td>
      <td>data 2</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</td>
      <td>data 2</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</td>
      <td>data 2</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">header 234567895678657</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>link 3</td>
    <td>link 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>link 3</td>
    <td>link 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>link 3</td>
    <td>link 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>link 3</td>
    <td>link 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This looks promising. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to other's answer,there are multiple ways you can show a table in mobile/responsive view .You can have a look here [responsive tables](http://exisweb.net/responsive-table-plugins-and-patterns).